# Simple openGL program won't pass compile

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glfw

I'm trying to compile a very simple program in openGL:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
            fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
            return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // Use OpenGL 3.X
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3); // Use openGL X.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);  
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 

    // Open a window and create OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window; // May be needed to make it global
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to pen GLFW window. If you have Intel GPU they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorial.\n");
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW.\n");
            return -1;
    }
}
```

However when i try to compile it with g++ i'm getting the following errors:

```
In function `main':
playground.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
playground.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
playground.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
playground.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
playground.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
playground.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
playground.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
playground.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
playground.cpp:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
playground.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
playground.cpp:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `glewInit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've found some posts to this specific problem and the solution seems to be to pass the required libraries as arguments to g++. However, when i do that, the problem still persists.

This is how i compile the code:

```
g++ -lglfw3 -pthread -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lrt -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -o openGLWindow openGLWindow.cpp
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: The library options belong **after** the name of the source file on the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when i try to compile it with g++ i'm getting the following errors:

No, your compilation is *just fine*. You are getting link errors, not compile errors.

The reason for your link errors is that your link command line is completely backwards. Try this instead:

```
g++ -pthread -o openGLWindow openGLWindow.cpp -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXinerama -lX11 -lrt -ldl
```

I am not sure the order of libraries above is correct, but it's certainly better than what you have. The order of sources, object files, and libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i changed the order of the arguments to the one you specified i got this error:  undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @M.Kostas That just means you need to add `-ldl` as well (add it at the end).

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to build and run my application in a terminal. (move in the application directory with cd exemple/c)
`gcc -o main main.c -I/usr/include -lglfw -lGL -GL -glut; sleep 0.1;./main`

I see where my applications was by this command in a shell/prompt/terminal
`pkg-config --libs --cflags --debug glfw3`